# Nestjs live reload not working with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I am using [Nestjs Mono repo](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo) and I am trying to live reload with docker-compose.

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

ENV NODE_ENV=development
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

And this is my service in docker-compose.yml

```
auth:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./apps/auth/Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
      - ./apps:/app/apps
    command: npm start
```

Here is the start command

```
nest start --watch
```

Service is working but it is not reloading on changes

Live reloading works properly on my local machine and in container if I don't use volume.

Nestjs version: 8.1.5

Update:

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1535) of nestjs/cli

Comment: When live reloading worked, the bind mount volume was set, there is no way it would have worked otherwise, check that all your files are saved then relaunch `docker-compose down` and `up`, should work right away.
Share some logs if any.

Comment: @Ludwig I checked the live reload inside docker doing SSH into the container and changing the file, but this doesn't work with bind mount. 

Also the changes from my code are reflected inside the container but it is not reloading.

There are normal startup logs and the service is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This may me a bit late, I had the same issue and i have tried all the available solutions and the only one that worked for me that was mentioned by @jbool24 at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73476289/4910054

solution is to start the nest with --tsc :

```
"start:dev": "nest start --tsc --watch"
```

Answer (score 1):

For future references: [Hot reload error](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly).

When you're using the NestJS CLI to start your application in watch mode it is done by calling tsc --watch, and as of version 4.9 of TypeScript, a new strategy for detecting file changes is used which is likely to be the cause of this problem. In order to fix this problem, you need to add a setting to your tsconfig.json file after the "compilerOptions" option as follows:

```
"watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "fixedPollingInterval"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's late but can help others.
you can add options to NestJS webpack's config

look at this reference about to config it:
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload

and when you did, add this options (your config file has to be like this):

```
module.exports = function (options) {
    options.watchOptions = {
        poll: 1000,
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
    }

    return options
};
```

you don't need to install dependencies that were told in the document (those are just for example). only install `webpack` as `--save-dev`