# nest start --watch not reloading after changes (nest start --watch not working)

Tags: nestjs

I have a nest.js installation. When I run npm run start:dev (which runs start --watch) everything works fine and the green logs appear.

[image]

The thing is that when I update something in the code, nest does not update anymore and it gets stuck in the following image:

[image]

I am sure this is not an issue with my code as I am having the same problem in all my nest.js repositories. I had also deleted node_modules and reinstalled them and it did not work.

I have also tried to reinstall the nest CLI globally.

My node version is 16.5.0 and npm 8.5.0

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "unigow-backend",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "env-cmd -f .env.production rimraf dist",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.production nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "env-cmd -f .env.development nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.production node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.3.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.0.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^8.0.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "dateformat": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "luxon": "^1.28.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.9",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rrule": "^2.6.8",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sib-api-v3-sdk": "^8.2.1",
    "stripe": "^8.183.0",
    "twilio": "^3.69.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Here is my ts config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.build:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "dist", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, is there any way to provide us with a minimal repo? I am unable to replicate this issue.

Comment: The thing is this is happening with all my nest.js projects (not just with a single one). And there is no way to reproduce the error on a different computer. I have tried to set up a virtual machine with arch Linux and everything works well there (inside the VM). The problem is on my computer (I have windows 10).

Comment: If the problem only exists on your machine, what are we supposed to do about it? You say no effort has been put in to solving this, but what is anyone else supposed to do here?

Comment: If you are having this issue only on your computer, are you able to run this from a Docker container for development instead?

Comment: Hi Jay, we talked in the nest.js discord. I think you belong to their support team. We were discussing my problem and you told me it has something to do with windows (that the problem only happened on windows). But no solution was provided to me (you told me i should switch to Linux for developing). As it is so particular my problem I assumed you consider it was not worthy to dig in further (which is totally understandable). I am not trying to offend anybody, I am just explaining my situation. I am sure someone else has face this problem.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have never used Docker. I can provide a little bit more of info though. When I run npm run start:dev, if there are any compilation errors (like a missing import inside a module), if I fix it then the green logs appear. But once everything is running fine and I add for example a console.log(), the server does not update, no green logs appear and I have to close the server and run npm run start:dev again

Comment: I have the same problem, tried reinstalling nodejs, clearing npm cache. Reinstalled nest cli - no luck...

Comment: I noticed that if you run the command line as administrator, everything works as it should.

Comment: I have also tried reinstalling and clearing everything but nothing worked. In my case running as administrator hasn´t worked either.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue with nestjs.

I don't know exactly what the problem is.

But this is how I solved it.

### First, install the required packages:

`npm i --save-dev webpack-node-externals run-script-webpack-plugin webpack`

### Once the installation is complete, create a **webpack-hmr.config.js** file in the root directory of your application.

```js
/* webpack-hmr.config.js file */
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const { RunScriptWebpackPlugin } = require('run-script-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (options, webpack) {
  return {
    ...options,
    entry: ['webpack/hot/poll?100', options.entry],
    externals: [
      nodeExternals({
        allowlist: ['webpack/hot/poll?100'],
      }),
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...options.plugins,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({
        paths: [/\.js$/, /\.d\.ts$/],
      }),
      new RunScriptWebpackPlugin({ name: options.output.filename }),
    ],
  };
};
```

### open the application entry file (main.ts) and add the following webpack-related instructions:

```js
declare const module: any;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => app.close());
  }
}
bootstrap();
```

### To simplify the execution process, add a script to your package.json file.

```json
"dev": "nest build --webpack --webpackPath webpack-hmr.config.js --watch"
```

### Now open your command line and run the following command:

```
npm run dev
```

[Hot Reload with webpack](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload)

Answer (score 3):

I think instead of altering the webpack configs it might be a better choice to override the build mechanism via the cli command flag. This way your production build is the same using webpack but in dev mode you compile typescript into your `/dist` directory. This also means one less file [webpack.config.js] that you don't need to maintain in your repo

Override command
scripts:

```
nest start --tsc --watch
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. In my case I was running WSL v2 and my test folder was still on my Windows partition. A know issues that file access speeds under WSL2 are terrible.

Running `npm run start:dev` from git-bash or powershell worked as expected, plus much improved initial compliation time.

For WSL, CD to your root and and then create your development folder from there. The compile time will be improved and `npm run start:dev` works out of the box with none of the hot reload config needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow these steps and it will recompile the changes without having to restart the server again.

https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload

Comment: Can you be more specific please? External links die sometimes, so including the main linked information here is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with nodemon on **windows** machine and now with nest.js. All what i have to to is run nodemon in [Legacy Mode](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#application-isnt-restarting), add `-L` flag. E.g. `nodemon -L ./src/index.js`. 
Maybe it's some help. 
Any ideas how to run nest.js app in legacy mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at the beginning.
but then I used **"nest g resource your_resource_name"**
and after that it worked just fine.
for an example,
after creating a nest js project. Say you want to create another controller, service and module named "User"
so write this command on terminal:

```
nest g resource resource User
```

or you can visit this [link](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/crud-generator) to better understanding.
Hope this might help you.